# Using parents(), closest from $(this) function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkbox like this:

```
<input class="checkField" onchange="freezeChildren()" type="checkbox" id ="tra"/>
```

and function to this:

```
function freezeChildren() {
    if (this !== null && $(this).is(":checked")) {
        var parent = $(this).closest("ul");
        var children = parent.find("input[type=checkbox]");
        children.prop("checked", false);
        children.prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

When I debug, problem is in this part:

```
$(this).closest("ul");
```

Jquery does not want to find up with parents/closest function from "this" - checkbox point. Context in visual studio is undifined.

Even this does not work:

```
$(this).parents('html');
```

Jquery works, because I checked this and worked:

```
$.find('html') or $.find('#tra').
```

I work on IE11. Can someone help?

Comment: tried $(this).parent().closest("ul"); ? eventually: parent(type) or parent().parent().closest("something") btw, keep in mind you can test in developer console in most of browser without reloading page, just paste the cody in js console and it should show you results straight away

Comment: What is your HTML structure?

Comment: onchange="freezeChildren()"  will not pass `this` You need `$("#tra").on("input", freezeChildren);`

Comment: `this !== null` is always true!

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - it is impossible to guess what you mean by children. It seems you want to disable more than one but likely not the one you are checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is pass event to the function, then use `event.currentTarget` to get the item that is being affected.

As you see here `onchange="freezeChildren()"` becomes `onchange="freezeChildren(event)"`

Then in the function we just utilize that property with `event.currentTarget`

```js
function freezeChildren(event) {
  let target = event.currentTarget
  if (target !== null && $(target).is(":checked")) {
    var parent = $(target).closest("ul");
    var children = parent.find("input[type=checkbox]");
    children.prop("checked", false);
    children.prop("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="checkField" onchange="freezeChildren(event)" type="checkbox" id="tra" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

### The jQuery Way

What you should do is remove the code from the html and use all jquery

```js
$(document).on('change', '.checkField', function(){
  let target = $(this)
  if (target.is(":checked")) {
    var parent = target.closest("ul");
    var children = parent.find("input[type=checkbox]");
    children.prop("checked", false);
    children.prop("disabled", true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="checkField" type="checkbox" id="tra" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or use unobtrusive coding instead of inline event handlers: `$("#tra").on("input", freezeChildren);`

Comment: Because it is more optimized than calling `$(this)` 100 times by using caching instead of the same function call over and over again.

Comment: True - missed the two calls

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `this` to the `onchange` callback:

```
<input class="checkField" onchange="freezeChildren(this)" type="checkbox" id ="tra"/>
```

and then `freezeChildren` needs a little tweak:

```
function freezeChildren(elem) { 
    if (elem !== null && $(elem).is(":checked")) {
        var parent = $(elem).closest("ul");
        var children = parent.find("input[type=checkbox]");
        children.prop("checked", false);
        children.prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Here is a working [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kinajoferi/):